# windows computer name and DNS

Tags: windows, dns, hostname

Let's say my computer name is "`MY_PC`". It will be "`MY_PC`" no matter which LAN I am currently connected to. So at home or at some open wirless access point, my computer name will be the same, right?

How does this come into play with DNS? The way I understand it, my computer's FQDN is used for DNS lookup. How does this work exactly?

When I connect my PC to a network, my PC sends its computer name to the nearest DNS server (usually the router, I guess) and is added to its DNS table?

I guess what I am asking is: What role does my computer's name play in my everyday internet activities. I was a little suprised to find out, it is the same in any network, but when is my computer's name actually used? Why does it have to be the same in any network?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer name has little to do with DNS unless it is joined to a domain. Even then the computer name is not a DNS entry.

A FQDN is something like www. google. com:

Each period represents a subgrouping

- www - is the world wide web group @
- google - this is the company owning that group which belongs to
- com - this is the entire group of companies in the united states with registered web addresses

The point of a DNS is to allow you to remember logical word groups instead of IP addresses (ie. it is easier to remember www.google.com, instead of 172.217.9.132).

Even on a company/private network the same is true, a DNS is used to allow a central administrator to assign names to certain network addresses.

When you assign your computer name it is similar but it not a DNS entry, as it is not administered on a centralized computer(s).

So if no one on your network, or outside of your network, need to easily remember where to find your computer (for some service) then you do not need a DNS entry.

This is just a basic version of why we use DNS. Other benefits include Disaster Recovery, ease of system migration and ease of building nested systems. Let me know if you would like me to elaborate further on this answer to accept it.